# How to call upon a switch statements return type

Tags: java, debugging, switch-statement

Alright, so i had this error with my game.
the error is in detail over here: https://www.rune-server.ee/runescape-development/rs2-server/help/668521-very-weird-backdoor-dupe.html

But to simply put it, the error was due to a user inputting a value which exceeded the int data type value, and it caused it to cheat the system.

so explain the bug to you, the user would go to the ingame store, and purchase something, when choosing the quantity of the item, he could input a value higher than the int value I'm assuming because of this, the price becomes negative and it allows the player to purchase an unlimited amount of the item, while also removing this negative amount that it costs from the players point which actually results in it being added (+) - (-) -> +.

The prices of those items where declared using a switch statement.

```
public int getSpecialItemValue14(int id) {// member points shop
    switch (id) {

    case 1038:
    case 1040:
    case 1042:
    case 1044:
    case 1046:
    case 1048:
        return 45000;
```

Now what im trying to do to prevent the server from accepting that value is create an IF STATEMENT, so that if the value exceeds the int value to block that request, and not forward it.

how would i do this?

Comment: Can you get the value entered by the player as a `BigInteger` and then run a check on that before using the value enetered in the switch?

Comment: Accept the value as `String`, then use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert it to an `Integer`. This method will throw an exception for any values outside the integer range

Comment: Everything related to this question should be in the body of the question. External links will eventually rot, making this question less useful.

Answer (score 1):

just convert the value to INTEGER before sending to the server, if it goes over the max value set it to 0 and launch the alert.

Comment: there is no ez way out, 3 ideas, try/catch, parseInt, and control the exception. round your code up with a try and catch, inside of it use a parseInt to convert the value to integer, if u get an exception then the value is not a integer value, then i will fire the catch part, there u set te value to 0 or 1, as u like, and return the value or a message, this is up to u.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check if price is negative or not? If it is, than you can display a message like "Error. Too many items".

Comment: i think i worded it wrong, the price is fine. its just the quantity of the item, the max quantity they can buy. if they exceed that value then it causes a problem and the max quantity is equal to the value of an int